# Is there a final Visit method to the Clang RecursiveASTVisitor?

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, clang++, libtooling

I couldn't find one looking at the API, but essentially I want the following: after all of the Visit* methods, I'd call a final method that does some postprocessing on my data members. I'd assume it'd be something similar to visiting a TranslationUnitDecl, except instead of being the first visit method, it'd be the last.

Answer (score 1):

You can add do this within a HandleTranslationUnit method.

```
void MyVisitor::HandleTranslationUnit(ASTContext &Context) {
  ...
  TraverseDecl(Context.getTranslationUnitDecl());
  // Do post-processing here
}
```

Comment: A bit unideal, since this is outside of the scope of the traversal and depends on whatever application calls the traversal to do the post-processing.